# In terms of satellite networks What exactly are RTSWnet/AFSCN and CDAS (NEN, DSN as needed)? Are they like TDRS but for strictly military data?

Tags: deep-space-network, military, satellite-constellation, solar-wind, tdrss

**Question:** In terms of satellite networks What exactly are RTSWnet/AFSCN and CDAS (NEN, DSN as needed)? Are they like TDRS but for strictly military data?

---

**BACKGROUND:**

In [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/43754/12102) to *Why Are EPIC/DSCOVR Images delayed for a day?* I discussed that DSCOVR's *space weather data* is sent to Earth in near-real time:

> According to eoPortal's [DSCOVR (Deep Space Climate Observatory)](https://directory.eoportal.org/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/d/dscovr):
>
> > **Sensor complement: (EPIC, NISTAR, PlasMag instrument suite, PHA)**
> >
> > The primary objective of the sensor complement is to measure the solar wind (np, vp, tp) and the interplanetary magnetic field at 240 RE forward of the Earth.
> >
> > The DSCOVR solar wind/IMF data will be downlinked to the Real Time Solar Wind Network (RTSWnet). 57)
> >
> > **Secondary mission objectives: Earth observations.** The Earth viewing instruments on DSCOVR have a continuous view of the entire sunlit face of the Earth.
> >
> > 57: [Changing of the Guard: Satellite Will Warn Earth of Solar Storms](https://eos.org/science-updates/changing-of-the-guard-satellite-will-warn-earth-of-solar-storms)
>
> You can see that the EPICS image data is downlinked to Wallops, from which DSCOVR might only be high enough in the sky for 8 hours a day or less in the winter, depending on its position within its Lissajous orbit around L2. So image downlinking will not be real near time.
>
> However the mission-critical Space Weather is downlinked via **RTSWnet/AFSCN** (Real Time Solar Wind net/[Air Force Satellite Control Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Force_Satellite_Control_Network); a division of Space Force!))
>
> Here's some [Real Time Solar Wind data](https://www.swpc.noaa.gov/products/real-time-solar-wind).
>
> [image: Space/Ground communications normal operations (image credit: NASA, NOAA)]
>
> > Figure 38: Space/Ground communications normal operations (image credit: NASA, NOAA)

Also, from Spaceflight 101's [DSCOVR](http://spaceflight101.com/dscovr/) there is this graphic showing **RTSWnet/CDAS (NEN, DSN as needed)**

[image]